# Scala: Best way to remove tuples from Seq where one value is None

Tags: scala

I wish to filter out `None` values where they appear in a Seq of tuples.
In the code below, I want to replace `getOrElse` with `get`. But then how do I remove the tuples where the first value is `None` ?

Here is my code. I feel it is inelegant.

```
myFirstMap.map {
  case (key, value) =>
    val tuple = (myLookUpMap.getOrElse(key,MyCaseClass("", None)), value.toString)
    tuple
}.filter(_._1.name.nonEmpty).toIndexedSeq
```

}

What is the correct way to do this?

NOTE: this method will be called thousands of times on Seq with length 40 to 100, so performance is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `.map()` and `.flatMap()` should do the trick, which is what a `for` comprehension is all about.

```
(for {
  (k, v) <- myFirstMap
  mcc    <- myLookUpMap.get(k)
} yield (mcc, v.toString)).toIndexedSeq
```

Answer (score 2):

`myFirstMap.collect { case (k, _) if myFilterMap.contains(k) => myFilterMap(k)}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
myFirstMap.map {
  case (key, value) =>
    myLookUpMap.get(key).map( found => Tuple2( found, value.toString ) )
}.withFilter(_.nonEmpty).map( _.get ).toIndexedSeq
```

...or more readably...

```
val mbTuples = myFirstMap.map {
  case (key, value) =>
    myLookUpMap.get(key).map( found => Tuple2( found, value.toString ) )
}
val foundTuples = mbTuples.withFilter(_.nonEmpty).map( _.get )
val tupleSeq = foundTuples.toIndexedSeq
```

Answer (score 1):

Or how about this approach:

```
val commonKeys = myFirstMap.keySet().intersect( myLookUpMap.keySet() )
val tupleSeq = commonKeys.map { case ( key, value ) =>
  ( myLookUpMap(key), value.toString )
}.toIndexedSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap to filter None in collection

`myFirstMap.flatMap { case (key, value) => myLookUpMap.get(key).map(entity => (entity, value.toString)) }`

Comment: You should certainly add some explanations around your answer, why would this work ? And also, please, can you format your code by adding backquotes characters ?